# Mesh led by noise

Tags: three.js, glsl

Just looking at http://lab.samsy.ninja/  intro experiment and wondering how it is done.

Must be an instanced geometry led by noise calculated using gpgpu.

But after fiddling a bit I got a headache wondering how to get the position from a simulated texture with noise for each vertex in a mesh? It would be easy for only particles representing a single pixel on a texture, but how to achieve it for a more complex geometry?

Maybe it is possible to read each pixel from such a simulated texture outside of the shader?
Render it to a canvas, traverse through each pixel and assign it to corresponding instance?

Any hints are more than welcome

Comment: this looks a bit similar to this one: https://github.com/spite/polygon-shredder – maybe the code there gives you some insights

Answer (score 1):

This is done via GPGPU in 2 rendering steps per frame.

1. First, they created a plane with custom shaders that has an RGB noise generator, but instead of rendering to the canvas, it's rendered to a [`THREE.WebGLRenderTarget`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget). The result is stored in a texture that can be accessed via [`WebGLRenderTarget.texture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget.texture).
2. Then they generated an instanced geometry with the colored bars you see in a second scene, where you can pass the stored texture from step 1 to the material with something like `material.noiseMap = target.texture;`. In the vertex shader, you can read the `RGB` channel of each pixel and assign it to the `XYZ` position of each vertex.

Here's a similar example available in the Three.js site for you to scan through the code: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=gpgpu#webgl_gpgpu_water

And here's a link to the standard GLSL noise generation functions: https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise/tree/master/src I think they used `psrdnoise2D.glsl` for this type of movement.